# Llamar a un FutureBuilder en un ElavatedButton

Tags: flutter, widget, android-widget

Hola tengo una consulta de identificación al dar click me consulta a un api-rest y debo mostrar en una lista los datos traidos, he puesto un FutureBuilder dentro del onPress,

```
child: ElevatedButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            cedula=txtcedula.text;
                         
                             FutureBuilder(
                                future: getDataPS(cedula),
                                builder: (BuildContext context,AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                                    return Text("Hoooooola${snapshot.data!.unidad}");
                                  }
                                  else if(snapshot.data==null)
                                    {
                                      return Text("NO tiene datos");
                                    }
                                  else if(snapshot.hasError)
                                    {
                                      return Text("Hubo un error");
                                    }

                                 else {
                                    return CircularProgressIndicator();
                                  }
                                });
```

Me trae los datos pero no me dibuja ningun widget, utilizo tambien esta alternativa,

```
getDataPS(cedula).then((name) => Text("Algun texto"));
```

Si le hago print por consula si imprime, debo estar haciendo algo mal, muchas gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¿De qué vale poner un FutureBuilder dentro de un botón? De nada. El FutureBuilder es un widget y como tal, debe situarse dentro del método build, como hijo directo del método o como hijo de algún otro widget. Si lo pones dentro del onPress, creas el widget, pero jamás lo dibujas.

Vayamos por partes.

**Primero, ¿cuál es el problema?**

Necesitas mostrar una serie de datos asíncronos, por lo que en primera instancia no se tienen dichos datos.

**Segundo, ¿qué estás intentando?**

Pa' serte sincero, no tengo idea de cómo has llegado a tremenda solución. Pero está bastante mal planteada. El onPreses no te va a mostrar los Widgets que pongas dentro. ¿Cómo o dónde te lo muestras? En ningún lado. No sabría dónde hacerlo.

Los Widgets se pintan dentro del método build, por ejemplo de un StatelessWidget. En dicho método, vamos anidando widgets y son esos los que se muestran.

**Tercero, ¿Cómo podría cargar datos asíncronos?**

Usando un StatefullWidget.

Lo mejor es que tengas en la clase state una variable inicializada a null donde guardes la información. Como en un primer momento, no la tienes, por eso en null y que dentro del método onPress llames a tu función asíncrona para obtener los datos. Cuando obtengas los datos, los almacenar en la variable y haces un setState(), para refrescar el estado.

Ya solo tendrías que hacer un if-else, dentro del método build que compruebe si la variable es null. Si es null que no muestre nada y si no lo es, que muestre los widgets necesarios.

**Consejo adicional.**

He visto varias preguntas tuyas y te diré, como consejo, que estás planteando dudas de lo mas sencillas. Primero que nada, te recomendaría seguir algún curso o leerte la documentación de Flutter y hacer algún codelab de los que hay en la página oficial. De esa forma, aprenderás más rápidamente a usar el framework y no te toparás con estos problemillas.

Por otro lado, creo que no estás usando ningún gestor de estado. Flutter usa para manejar el estado StatefullWidget y como axuliar InheritedWidget. Como usar dichos widgets para manejar el estado puede ser tedioso, hay muchísimos paquetes desarrollados por la comunidad que te podrían ayudar muchísimo en el desarrollo de tu app. Entre ellos están GetX, Provider, FlutterBlox, Riverpod, etc. Te aconsejo que le eches un ojo y te plantees seriamente el usarlos.